Expected payoff of non martingale
Let $X_n$ be i.i.d with mean $p$ and $T$ a stopping time. $S_n = \sum X_n$ is not a martingale, but I need to find $\mathbb{E}(S_T)$. If $S_T$ only has 2 values, there are tricks one can use by calulating $\mathbb{E}(N_T)$ where $N$ is a martingale and related to $S$. But how do I do this in general when $S_T$ has many values?

You have that $$\mathbb E[S_T]=\mathbb E\big[\mathbb E[S_T\mid T]\big].$$
Moreover, $$\mathbb E[S_T\mid T=t]=\mathbb E[S_t]=tp,$$
and thus $$\mathbb E[S_T\mid T]=pT.$$
Therefore $$\mathbb E[S_T]=p\mathbb E[T].$$

Could you clarify where you use independence and the fact T is a stopping time?

Probably, the equality $\mathbb E[S_T\mid T=t]=\mathbb E[S_t]$ wouldn't be true if $T$ wouldn't be a stopping time, and $X_n$'s wouldn't be independent. But I'm not so sure to be honest. However, the fact that ${T\leq t}\in \mathcal F_t$ as well as $X_1,...,X_t\in \mathcal F_t$ seems indeed crucial. For the independence I don't really know. Could you please clarify it ? Tks (for asking the question and for the answer :-) ) @Pedro

$\mathbb{E}(T)$ is even harder to calculate. In fact, in one of my textbook exercises (probability and martingales), they calculates $\mathbb{E}(S_T)$ first, then use it to find $\mathbb{E}(T)$. You can just use the martingale $N_n = S_n - n(p-q)$, where $p-q$ is the mean of the $X_n$ (so $p-q$ is equal to my $p$ defined above), to find a relationship between $\mathbb{E}(T)$ and $\mathbb{E}(S_T)$. This doesnt calculate either quantity.

When $S_T$ has only 2 values (a, b), they calculate $\mathbb{E}(S_T)$ by using the martingale $\left(\frac{q}{p} \right)^{S_n}$ to find simultaneous equations for $\mathbb{P}(S_T = a)$ and $\mathbb{P}(S_T = b)$. But in my problem, I have 6 possible values for $S_T$.
